# Contando array erroneamente

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer uma estrutura if que depende do número de conteúdo em um array e pelo visto está contando errado, porque independente do tanto de conteúdo que eu seleciono ele me redireciona para a página que eu pedi em uma condição:

```
else if(isset($_POST['alterar'])){
            foreach ($_POST['selecionado'] as $cpf){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE cpf = '$cpf'";
                $result = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro no acesso aos dados');</script>");
                $linhas[] += $result;
            }
            if(count($linhas) == 1){
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='cadastro.php';</script>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Escolha uma linha apenas');</script>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: sempre cai no else? já tentou dar um `var_dump($linhas)` ?

Comment: cai no if sempre, o que seria um var_dump ?

Comment: Quando vc faz `$array[] = 'alguma coisa';` ele adiciona um elemento novo. Parece que está faltando o `mysqli_fetch()`

Comment: o problema é que no mysqli_fetch não se pode fazer $linhas += mysqli_fetch_array($result), então ele sempre vai criar um novo $linhas e não adicionar mais linhas em um mesmo array, a estrutura é um foreach... já tentei com o fetch e não deu mt certo

Comment: O que você deseja que seu código faça? mais de um cpf pode ser enviado?

Comment: Não, exatamente o contrário primeiro ele conta quantos cpfs estão sendo selecionados, se for mais de um ou 0 ele da erro se for só 1 ele passa pra outra janela em que eu irei colocar os dados referentes á esse cpf dentro de alguns textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se precisa saber quantos registros foram encontrados na consulta simplifique use a função `mysqli_num_rows()`. Se somente um cpf form enviado pelo form remova aquele `foreach`

```
else if(isset($_POST['alterar'])){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE cpf = '{$_POST['selecionado']}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro no acesso aos dados');</script>");
    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($linhas == 1){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='cadastro.php';</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Escolha uma linha apenas');</script>";
    }
}
```

O código abaixo executa uma consulta e pode retornar um false se a consulta falhar ou um resource se tiver sucesso. Se o `foreach` estiver sobrando aí `$linhas` sempre terá somente um elemento, que faz cair no if sempre.

```
foreach ($_POST['selecionado'] as $cpf){
  //linhas omitidas
  $result = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql);
  $linhas[] += $result;
```

Comment: ai que está, o selecionado é um array de checkbox em que cada um armazena um valor cpf, essa sua resposta ia pegar apenas um cpf

Comment: @CaioVieira essa informação dos checkbox não tinha pergunta e pelo [comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167904/contando-array-erroneamente/167910#comment345727_167904) deu a entender que apenas um cpf era enviado. Nesse caso eu faria uma página a parte com os textbox e daria include no lugar de redirecionar.

Comment: acabou que deu certo aqui rray, o erro era lá em cima no action que estava action="cadastro.php", retirei ele e deu certo, só que agora eu não sei como que eu mando os resultados do meu array para a outra página, outro formulário dentro dos textbox dele...

Answer (score -1):

Tenta inicializar a array antes do foreach e inserir o elemento na array pelo método push

array_push($linhas, $result);